# Microsoft Chart Control labels

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

I've been searching for a while and browsing through the samples but could not find a solution to my problem.

In Microsoft Chart Control I have created a line series that plots real-time data. As new data points are added, the chart margins will sometimes jump on the form. I have tried disabling the grid lines and have determined that the margins change when the x-axis label overlaps with the y-axis label. I have tried auto-fitting the labels but that does not seem to work probably because it treat x-axis and y-axis separately. Is there any way to prevent the overlap, or keep the labels and corresponding grid lines stationery and just change their value when the data scrolls?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set IsEndLabelVisible = false to solve this problem.